# JavaScript: Get next element from Parent

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable the next element of the parent of a tag:
HTML:

```
<span>     
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="disableInput(this)">     
</span>
<input type="text" />
<!-- When checkbox changed, disable inputfield -->
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function disableInput(element){
        element.parentNode.nextSibling.disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

This didn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: You'll find the `nextSibling` is a text node. Remove the white-space between `</span>` and `<input..` and you'll see results. http://jsfiddle.net/LaTsd/

Comment: Remove the white space between the closing span and input and it works.

Comment: There is no error, I didn't work

Comment: @j08691 It Works! But how can I fix this, because in my code is it proper to indent and break lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. `nextSibling` includes text nodes (including empty space), but `nextElementSibling` doesn't.

```
function disableInput(element) {
  element.parentNode.nextElementSibling.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nextElementSibling`

```
  function disableInput(element){
        element.parentNode.nextElementSibling.disabled = true;
  }
```

It will select actual DOM element. The drawback - this may not be compatible with older browsers like IE8.